# Why Bash script in azure devops not working?

Tags: bash, azure

In Azure Devops classic pipeline use bash scipt with inline command:
alias tf="cd /var" && tf
After pipeline running it's get error tf command not found
Can help me with this

Answer (score 0):

From [Aliases](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Aliases) in the manual:

> Aliases are not expanded when the shell is not interactive, unless the `expand_aliases` shell option is set using [`shopt`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Shopt-Builtin)